# performance about apache activemq using ssl

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

By default, the activemq uses tcp protocol. But now, I change it to use ssl.

If I deploy the publisher and server on one machine, it makes no difference with regard to the speed. But after I deploy them on different machine, it's much slower to use ssl than to use tcp. Is this normal? If not, what's probably wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how much slower your application is working.

If you process huge amount of data volumes, SSL will take a decent amount of CPU cycles to encrypt (and also decrypt) the data. Is it the ActiveMQ server that is slower or is it the client. Profile the system setup to get an overview where to find the bottenecks.

Another possibillity is frequent hand shakes. Say your client code (can you post it?) to send messages by opening a connection for each message, it might be the case that the latency for sending a message will suffer from the increased SSL handshake time compared to plain tcp.

UPDATE:

A speed up would be to reuse your connection. A SSL handshake has to be done for every message sent in your case which involves cpu expensive asymmetric crypto and a few more tcp roundtrips than plain TCP. It is easy to do, with the pooling connection factory provided by activemq. This example does not alter your code much:

```
public class MySender{
 private static ConnectionFactory factory = new org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory("ssl://192.168.0.111:61616");
 public void send(){
  Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
  Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  Topic topic = session.createTopic(newDataEvent.getDataType().getType());
  MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
  TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
  message.setText(xstream.toXML(newDataEvent));
  producer.send(message);
  session.close();
  connection.close(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, data is very small. This is the code of the publisher:
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("ssl://192.168.0.111:61616");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic(newDataEvent.getDataType().getType());
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
message.setText(xstream.toXML(newDataEvent));
producer.send(message);
session.close();
connection.close();

Comment: The newDataEvent object just contains some very same data.

Comment: Also, when the publisher is initialized, I set system properties for keystore, keystorepassword, truststore, truststorepassword

Comment: Hi, I am still having problem. Here are the questions:
1) Your code doesn't work. eclipse shows that I have to use PooledConnectionFactory factory = new PooledConnectionFactory(""), but then I got the exception: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/ObjectPoolFactory.
2) The handshake happens when creating connection or session? My publisher is a thread, so when initialized, I created only one connection, but for each message, I create a new session, and I still face the performance problem.
Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: um..my bad, I forgot to import a jar file. It works now. Really thanks, man!

Comment: Nice. Just curious, how much speedup did you get?

Comment: Actually, I have a thread that continually send messages every 2 seconds. Without PooledConnectionFactory, it takes about 10 seconds for each message to be sent out. But with PooledConnectionFactory, only the first message takes about 10 seconds, after that, every message just needs 2 seconds.